# Turn off TRACE in GlassFish v2

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

I need to turn off TRACE to help close XST security vulnerabilities.
I've been looking, nothing obvious so far.
Any help?

Comment: set enableTrace to false in http-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set enableTrace to false in http-service

Answer (score 2):

"set enableTrace to false in http-service"
matches [Jeanfrancois Arcand's answer](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/servlets/ReadMsg?list=users&msgNo=26108).  JFA's answer has the 'syntax'.  You will need to make the change in the domain.xml file.  That file is in the config directory of your domain.  The path to that file is (typically) GFINSTALL/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml